# Refresh disks on live system without rebooting

Tags: centos, ssh, hard-drive, filesystems, centos6

I have 4 drives in a server. This is a live server. One of these drives I replaced with a different drive and changed the mount point for the new drive so as to avoid confusion.

After completing the initialization and mounting the new disk in place of the old, as well as updating `/etc/fstab`, the command `df -h` still shows the old drive. Rebooting could solve the issue, but this is a live server that I don't want to take down for the 10 or so minutes it will take for the reboot (I know the time because I've rebooted before and the root drive is not a SSD).

Here is my abbreviated output of the `df -h`, with a notation about which is the new and old drive:

```
/dev/mapper/vg-root  ... /
...
/dev/sdb1            ... /home3 << old drive (removed)
/dev/sdc1            ... /home4 
/dev/sdd1            ... /home5
/dev/sde1            ... /home6 << new drive (working)
```

Instead, I would like to refresh the disks showing in `df -h` without rebooting the server. What command in ssh will achieve this without rebooting the server?

Comment: have you tried umount path_to_mount_point ?

Comment: You should have unmounted the filesystem before removing its underlying drive. You're probably going to get OS errors now if you try to unmount it.

Comment: in the future what I have now done is unmount the drive.
when it wouldn't unmount, i actually shut down the server to achieve the task safely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try partprobe  command, this command refresh the change in the partition table, after that try mount -a -o remount ( to remount all partitions again).